# Convert dates written in Excel Format to Stata

Tags: excel, string, date, stata, data-conversion

I have dates in a CSV file saved from excel. The dates are written as the number of days since Jan 1, 1900. How do I convert these for use in Stata? In particular, I'm interested in extracting the month and day? [Screen Shot of Day Format Provided in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxpIo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of origin is indicated by these examples

```
. di mdy(1, 1, 1960)
0

. di mdy(1, 1, 1900)
-21914

. di %td  mdy(1, 1, 1900) + 21914
01jan1960
```

from which I gather that your first date is in conventional terms 18 July 2019.

```
. di %td 43662 - 21914
18jul2019
```

Your dates appear to be 2 weeks apart, so be sure to declare `delta(14)` to `tsset` or `xtset`.

See `help datetime` for standard extraction functions.

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of declaring the fact that the dates are two weeks apart? What happens, for instance, if you do not declare this?

Comment: Otherwise your dataset will appear to be daily data but mostly gaps, so references to previous and following values, differences, and so forth will all return missing values. This is explained at length in the help for `tsset`. .